# How to use CopyFile for copying a particular type of files from one folder to another

Tags: c++, c, winapi

How to use `CopyFile` for copying specific type of files from one folder to a backup file (`backup.bkp`)

Example:

```
C:\HHH
  abc.jpeg
  def.txt
  ghi.jpeg
```

I want to copy only jpeg files to the `backup.bkp` file

I tried the below syntax but it is not working,

```
CopyFile( _T("C:\\HHH\*.jpeg"),_T("C:\\Backup.bak", FALSE);
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Is `HHH` a directory and `abc.jpeg`, `def.txt` and `ghi.jpeg` files under this directory ?

Comment: Yes, C:\HHH  is directory

Comment: I have forgot one last question: is Backcup.bak already existing ? Or should it be created first ?

Comment: How would you unjumble the 3 files from the bak file with no structured format?

Comment: @mikedu- We have to create Backcup.bak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the destination directory already exists.

`CopyFile` simply copy one file to another one. A quick solution consists in using the standard C `system` function to run the command to copy the files (using `copy` or `xcopy` for example), but that gives you less control.

So sticking with `CopyFile`, you need to list all `*.jpeg` files from the `HHH` directory first, then copy each of them into the destination directory.

You will also often need to split/concatenate paths during the processing, and though you can do that manually by using `strcpy`, `strcat`, etc. You've better to use dedicated functions like the `splitpath` and `makepath` family of functions or equivalents.

That leads us to following sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>

int main(void) {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA File;
    HANDLE hSearch;

    TCHAR SourcePath[_MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR SourceDrive[_MAX_DRIVE];
    TCHAR SourceDir[_MAX_DIR];
    TCHAR SourceFname[_MAX_FNAME];
    TCHAR SourceExt[_MAX_EXT];

    TCHAR DestPath[_MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR DestDrive[_MAX_DRIVE];
    TCHAR DestDir[_MAX_DIR];

    LPCTSTR lpszFindPattern = TEXT("C:\\HHH\\*.jpeg");

    _tsplitpath_s(_T("C:\\HHH\\"), SourceDrive, _MAX_DRIVE, SourceDir, _MAX_DIR, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
    _tsplitpath_s(_T("C:\\Backup.bak\\"), DestDrive, _MAX_DRIVE, DestDir, _MAX_DIR, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

    hSearch = FindFirstFile(lpszFindPattern, &File);
    if (hSearch != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            _tsplitpath_s(File.cFileName, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, SourceFname, _MAX_FNAME, SourceExt, _MAX_EXT);

            _tmakepath_s(SourcePath, _MAX_PATH, SourceDrive, SourceDir, SourceFname, SourceExt);
            _tmakepath_s(DestPath, _MAX_PATH, DestDrive, DestDir, SourceFname, SourceExt);

            CopyFile(SourcePath, DestPath, FALSE);
        } while (FindNextFile(hSearch, &File));

        FindClose(hSearch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion Mikedu95

Answer (score 3):

CopyFile doesn't accept wild cards or copy multiple files. It can copy a single file from one fully specified place to another.

To achieve what you want you need to enumerate over the directory using [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx)/[FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx) and copy the files one by one using CopyFile. These functions take wildcards or you can ask for all files, and do the filtering yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`CopyFile()` does not support what you are asking for.  You would have to manually loop through the source directory locating the desired files and then copy them one at a time.

A better solution is to let the OS do the work for you.  You can use the [`SHFileOperation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) function for that:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT op = {0};
op.hwnd = hwnd;
op.wFunc = FO_COPY;
op.pFrom = TEXT("C:\\HHH\\*.jpeg\0"); // note the extra null terminator!
op.pTo = TEXT("C:\\Backup.bak\\\0"); // note the extra null terminator!
op.fFlags = FOF_FILESONLY | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NORECURSION | FOF_SILENT;

if (SHFileOperation(&op) != 0)
{
    // error...
}
else
{
    if (op.fAnyOperationsAborted)
    {
        // not all files copied...
    }
}
```

On Vista and later, `SHFileOperation()` has been deprecated by [`IFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx), but unfortunately it does not support wildcards at all, so you would have to enumerate the files manually first, passing each file to `IFileOperation::CopyItem()`, or putting them in an array that you can then pass to `IFileOperation::CopyItems()`, and then finally call `IFileOperation::PerformOperations()` to perform the actual copy.

Comment: I prefer this one. I went through the msdn link for SHFileOperation, its saying "This function has been replaced in Windows Vista by IFileOperation" and the minimum supported client is Windows XP.

I have a doubt on this , its only repleced in Vista is it? what about windows 8?

Comment: `SHFileOperation()` was indeed replaced **starting in** Vista, and has been the preferred API by Microsoft moving forward. But like most older APIs, `SHFileOperation()` is still functional in modern Windows versions. In any case, `SHFileOperation()` is fine if you just want to copy the files and don't really care about the particulars. But using `FindFirstFile()` with `CopyFile()` or `IFileOperation` will allow you to discover which specific files are copied successfully and which files fail. `SHFileOperation()` can't tell you that.